# Java User Agent

Tags: java, user-agent

I have recently started seeing user agents like Java/1.6.0_14 (and variations) on my site

What does this mean. Is it a browser or bot or what

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This likely means someone is crawling your website using Java.  This isn't much of anything to be concerned about unless you notice the crawler using large amounts of your bandwidth or not respecting your robots.txt file.  Usually legitimate crawlers will take the time to create custom user agent to make it easy to contact the crawler if you have a problem, but even if they're using the default user agent, it's more than likely perfectly benign.

However, if you do notice a spike in 404 hits or *lots* of hits from the Java client, you're likely under attack by spammers looking for security holes in your website.  If your site is built well, there's not a whole lot they can do other than burn some of your bandwidth, but if they find a security hole, they'll be sure to exploit it.  Dealing with spammers properly is beyond the scope of this answer, but a scorched earth solution (which will work as a short term fix at the very least) would be to block all user agents that contain the string 'java'.

Comment: Couldn't this block some android tablets and such? I mean, maybe the java version is in theUA, but not necessarily because they are using Java's UrlConnection.

Comment: Absolutely, it's a scorched earth solution because it's fast and effective, but will have other negative consequences.  Blocking all Java user agents will block legitimate visitors, but can quickly block certain attacks.  That said, I don't think it will impact most Android platforms, a quick Google for [Android User Agents](http://www.gtrifonov.com/2011/04/15/google-android-user-agent-strings-2/) didn't show up any that contained 'java' in their strings - likely very intentionally to avoid being confused with a Java crawler.

Comment: Just a quick note: Google search blocks java user agents. "Your client does not have permission to get URL /search" - just try it out with a user agent switcher plugin and set user agent to e.g. Java/1.8.0_45. Generally a decent Java app should set it's user agent string to reflect the app's name/prupose, so "Java/version" is most likely not a legitimate user.

Comment: @TorinFinnemann Google's [Terms of Service](http://www.google.com/intl/en/policies/terms/) forbid any sort of scraper, regardless of user agent.

Comment: That may be. It does not block my browser if the user agent is set to "MyJavaBrowser", but it does block "Java/1.8.0_45". My main point was that a legitimate user agent -be that crawler or browser- would identify itself properly in the User Agent string. Exemplifying using google was merely to illustrate that "Java/<Version>" is very unlikely to be part of any legit browser's User Agent string, since that would make users of the browser unable to use google.com/search. This in turn brought me to conclude that blocking e.g. "^(Java/\d\.\d)" would be "safe" (albeit incomplete).

Answer (score 5):

It means your site is being accessed through the JVM on someones machine. It could be a crawler or simply someone scraping data. You can replicate the user-agent string using the [HttpURLConnection](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html) class. Here is a sample:

```
import java.net.*;

public class Request {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {       
            URL url=new URL("http://google.ca");
            HttpURLConnection con=(HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
            con.connect();
            System.out.println(con.getResponseCode());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Java's [`HttpURLConnection`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html) class will send the JVM version information as the `User-Agent` header.